# Spring boot - Log GET request URL for end point with multiple values

Tags: spring-boot

I have an end point with the following:

```
@GetMapping(value = {"/foo", "/bar"})
public String myFunciton() {
     // TODO: log '/foo' or '/bar'
     ...
}
```

How can I log which path was used (eg. /foo or /bar)?

Comment: by making two @GetMapping annotated functions, that both call the same function. Then you log in each of the two functions

Comment: I realize that but I was really hoping to be able to pull that info in the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `request.getRequestURI();`

```
myFunciton(HttpServletRequest request)
```